# Python/Django - Testing against a list

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm new to testing in python and testing in general and looking for a way to write one test function and run this function multiple times against different elements of a tuple.

More precisely, there is a **tuple consisting of different database queries which i all want to test**. The results of all those queries share the same pattern so i guess it's reasonable to reuse the code testing those results.

As far as i know, it is considered bad practice to pass arguments to a unittest which seems reasonable too. This leaves me a bit clueless. Writing one function for every single query would be hard to maintain, because new **queries are added to this tuple constantly**.
I also would like to obtain detailed results (FAIL or ok) for every single element of the tuple via `python manage.py test myapp -v=2`, therefore putting the complete tuple in one execution of a function seems like a bad approach too.

Like the headline suggests, my code lives in a django environment.
I'd be happy to use the django testing framwork so i can execute this test using `python manage.py test`.

What would be a good approach to implement this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are sometimes called parameterized tests and [nose-parameterized](https://github.com/wolever/parameterized) is an awesome python package that supports it.

It allows you to define a single test function and provide a collection of parameters.  It will dynamically create a named reference-able test function for each parameter provided.

---

How large is the tuple? Is it really necessary to test every single query in the tuple? If they share the same pattern is it sufficient to only take a subset of the queries?

Comment: Should really include example code here, Otherwise this feels like a link-only answer

Comment: link answer is fine. I'm rather looking for a framework, library etc. since pure python/django doesn't seem to support what i want to do. Thanks for the link, will check it out shortly!

Comment: Yes, i absolutely want to test every single query (right now around 150, more will be added soon). Since it is hard to maintain the quality of all this db related code, i want to test it extensively

Comment: Great package. Does exactly what i want it to do. Works even with 3.6 even though 3.6 is not explicitely supported.